# Strange tube leak

Tags: innertube, bmx

So I have this bmx bike where the back tire's inner tube was leaking air and I'd have to inflate it every day or so. And I just got a new tube and it's having the same issue. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: If the air is coming out of the tube, its exiting through either a hole, or a weakness in the valve.  Use the dunk test on the tube to find the hole and then patch it.   Then search the tyre/rim for the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you replace a tube you should run your hands along the inside wall of the tire carefully. You'll be able to feel if there is a thorn or other sharp object that is puncturing your tubes as fast as you can replace them.